# A constrained minimum edge coloring

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, permutations, ramsey-theory

Is minimum number of colors needed to color edges of complete graph $K_n$ so that every even simple cycle contains at least one color assigned to odd number of edges at most $\beta n$ where $\beta\geq1$ is fixed?

Previous question had asked lower bounds as well which Kevin P. Costello's, Daniel Soltész's comments have answered.

Comment: Oh, so by "color assigned to an even number of edges" you mean that "color assigned to an even number of edges of this cycle".

Comment: Reiman showed that any graph on $n$ vertices with more than roughly $\frac{1}{2} n^{3/2}$ edges must contain a $4$-cycle.  So if your coloring involves much fewer than $\sqrt{n}$ colors, whichever color has the most edges automatically has such a cycle, which would violate your condition.

Comment: Replace in Kevin P. Costello's comment, $C_4$ with even cycle, and $n^{3/2}$ with $3(n-1)/2$ and you got yourself a linear bound.